# Artificial inteligence in python and pygame for Pong clone

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pygame

I'm making a program that clones pong based off a tutorial and I already have the program to where it is multiplayer with two separate people. I want to add an AI in the program instead of a player 2. I've been stuck on this for quite some time and would appreciate any help! Here is the code currently:

`import sys, os, math, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *`

`class paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):`

```
def __init__(self, xy):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', 'pong_paddle.gif'))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = xy

    self.movementspeed = 5

    self.velocity = 0

def up(self):
    # increases vertical velocity
    self.velocity -= self.movementspeed

def down(self):
    # decreases vertical velocity
    self.velocity += self.movementspeed

def move(self, dy):
    # moves the paddle y, doesn't go out of top or bottom
    if self.rect.bottom + dy > 400:
        self.rect.bottom = 400
    elif self.rect.top + dy < 0:
        self.rect.top = 0
    else:
        self.rect.y += dy

def update(self):
    # makes the paddle move every frame
    self.move(self.velocity)
```

`class aiplayer(object):`

```
def __init__(self):
    self.bias = random.random() - 0.5
    self.hit_count = 0



def update(self, paddle, game,):


    if (paddle.rect.centerx < game.bounds.centerx and game.ball.rect.centerx < game.bounds.centerx) or (paddle.rect.centerx > game.bounds.centerx and game.ball.rect.centerx > game.bounds.centerx):
        delta = (paddle.rect.centery + self.bias * paddle.rect.height) - game.ball.rect.centery 
        if abs(delta) > paddle.velocity:
            if delta > 0:
                paddle.direction = -1
            else:
                paddle.direction = 1
        else:
            paddle.direction = 0
    else:
        paddle.direction = 0

def hit(self):
    self.hit_count += 1
    if self.hit_count > 6:
        self.bias = random.random() - 0.5
        self.hit_count = 0

def lost(self):
    self.bias = random.random() - 0.5

    def won(self):
        pass


def render(self, surface):

    x, y = self.location
    w, h = self.image.get_size()
    surface.blitz(self.image, (x-w/2, y-h/2))
```

`class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):`

```
def __init__(self, xy):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', 'pong_ball.gif'))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = xy
    self.maxspeed = 10
    self.servespeed = 5
    self.velx = 0
    self.vely = 0

def reset(self):
    self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery = 400, 200
    self.velx = 0
    self.vely = 0

def serve(self):
    angle = random.randint(-45, 45)

    if abs(angle) < 5 or abs(angle-180) < 5:
        angle = random.randint(10, 20)

    if random.random() > .5:
        angle += 180

    # this gets the velocity for the x and y coords
    x = math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    y = math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    self.velx = self.servespeed * x
    self.vely = self.servespeed * y
```

`class Game(object):`

```
def __init__(self):

    pygame.init()

    # creates the window
    self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))

    # makes a clock
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # window title
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

    # tells pygame to watch for these certain events so we can close window
    pygame.event.set_allowed([QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP])

    self.background = pygame.Surface((800, 400))
    self.background.fill((55, 255, 85))
    pygame.draw.line(self.background, (0,0,0), (400, 0), (400, 400), 2)
    self.window.blit(self.background, (0,0))
    #lets the background show up
    pygame.display.flip()



    #renders the sprites so that they actually show up
    self.sprites = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()

    # makes the paddles, adds to sprite group
    self.leftpaddle = paddle((50, 200))
    self.sprites.add(self.leftpaddle)
    self.rightpaddle = paddle((750, 200))
    self.sprites.add(self.rightpaddle)

    # makes the ball
    self.ball = Ball((400, 200))
    self.sprites.add(self.ball)


def run(self):
    # this lets the game run using a loop so its always active and never closes
    running = True

    while running:
        self.clock.tick(60)

        # pygame event, if user closes the game, then stop running
        running = self.handleEvents()

        pygame.display.set_caption("Pong %d fps" % self.clock.get_fps())

        self.manageBall()

        # updates the sprites(paddles, ball)
        for sprite in self.sprites:
            sprite.update()

        # renders the sprites
        self.sprites.clear(self.window, self.background)
        dirty = self.sprites.draw(self.window)
        pygame.display.update(dirty)

def handleEvents(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            return False

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return False

            # controls the right paddle
            if event.key == K_w:
                self.leftpaddle.up()
            if event.key == K_s:
                self.leftpaddle.down()
            if event.key == K_UP:
                self.rightpaddle.up()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                self.rightpaddle.down()

            # serves the ball
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if self.ball.velx == 0 and self.ball.vely == 0:
                    self.ball.serve()

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_w:
                self.leftpaddle.down()
            if event.key == K_s:
                self.leftpaddle.up()
            if event.key == K_UP:
                self.rightpaddle.down()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                self.rightpaddle.up()

        elif event.type == 


    return True



def manageBall(self):

    # this moves the ball
    self.ball.rect.x += self.ball.velx
    self.ball.rect.y += self.ball.vely

    if self.ball.rect.top < 0:
        self.ball.rect.top = 1

        # makes the ball bounce
        self.ball.vely *= -1

    elif self.ball.rect.bottom > 400:
        self.ball.rect.bottom = 399

        # makes ball bounce off bottom
        self.ball.vely *= -1

    # resets the ball if it hits the left or right screen
    if self.ball.rect.left < 0:
        self.ball.reset()
        return

    elif self.ball.rect.right > 800:
        self.ball.reset()
        return

    collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.ball, [self.leftpaddle, self.rightpaddle], dokill = False)

    if len(collision) > 0:
        hitpaddle = collision[0]

        # sends the ball back
        self.ball.velx *= -1

        # makes sure the ball doesn't get stuck in the paddle
        self.ball.rect.x += self.ball.velx
```

`# makes the game and runs it`
`if __name__ == '__main__':`
    `game = Game()`
    `game.run()`

Comment: You should provide a more specific question.

Comment: Have you considered a function that is called every x milliseconds, looks at where the ball is, and moves the paddle towards the ball? You can register it as an event, as well.

Comment: it's not really "AI" you are after is it? If the paddle is "under" the ball the move it up, if it's "over" the ball move it down.

Comment: I agree with JohnnyMopp the question should be more specific

Comment: I am looking for an AI, as you can see in my class aiplayer i tried to make it to where the ai will follow the ball around, but i don't quit know how to implement the ai into the rest of the code so that it will run with it. I will try that idea Shurane

Comment: Well actually yes Paul C, that is basically what I want

Answer (score 0):

Make a function AI in the aiplayer and have it return up or down

```
int AI(self.position,ball.position):
       if self.y>ball.y:
            return -1
       elif self.y<ball.y:
             return 1
```

then, in the update() code for aiplayer, do something similar to this

```
self.y += movespeed*AI(self.position,ball.position)
```

Then, it either moves the paddle up or down depending on where the ball is ( you might need to switch if you add or subtract the movespeed to get the paddle to go the right direction). Also, it might be more effective to use the center of the paddle so that it won't put the top or bottom edge of the paddle at the ball.

Comment: I did what you stated and called the aiplayer function in the game function in hopes that it would run but in the python shell i got the error message 'Game' object has no attribute 'aiplayer'. Any ideas on what that means, I tried to fix it but can't seem to get it.

Comment: did you put the AI function in the aiplayer class? If you didnt, make sure you do. Then, if that doesn't fix it, call self.AI() instead of AI()